# How to find duplicate pairs in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, dictionary

I'd like to calculate the TCC metric:

> The Tight Class Cohesion (TCC)
>   measures the ratio of the number of
>   method pairs of directly connected
>   visible methods in a class NDC(C) and
>   the number of maximal possible method
>   pairs of connections between the
>   visible methods of a class NP(C). Two
>   visible methods are directly
>   connected, if they are accessing the
>   same instance variables of the class.
>   n is the number of visible methods
>   leading to:

```
NP(C) = (n(n-1))/2
```

and

```
TCC(C) = NDC(C) / NP(C)
```

So i wrote a method that parse through all methods in the class i want to check. This method stores all methods in that class and there fields they are using in a dictionary that looks like this:

```
Dictionary<MethodDefinition, IList<FieldReference>> references = new Dictionary<MethodDefinition, IList<FieldReference>>();
```

So now, how do I iterate through this dictionnary to check the condition mentioned above? If I understand it correctly I have to find these two pairs of methods that are using the same set of fields? Then how can I do this the best way? I think I have to iterate over the dictionary and see if the IList contains the same set? (even not in the same order)?

Any oder ideas`?

My code is the following, but it does not work correctly:

```
class TCC
    {

        public static int calculate(TypeDefinition type)
        {
            int count = 0;


            Dictionary<MethodDefinition, HashSet<FieldReference>> references = new Dictionary<MethodDefinition, HashSet<FieldReference>>();

            foreach (MethodDefinition method in type.Methods)
            {
                if (method.IsPublic)
                {
                    references.Add(method, calculateReferences(method));
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < references.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                HashSet<FieldReference> list = new HashSet<FieldReference>();
                references.TryGetValue(references.Keys.ElementAt(i), out list);

                if (isPair(references, list)) {
                    count++;
                }

            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                count = count / 2;
            }

            return count;
        }

        private static bool isPair(Dictionary<MethodDefinition, HashSet<FieldReference>> references, HashSet<FieldReference> compare)
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < references.Keys.Count; j++)
                {
                    HashSet<FieldReference> compareList = new HashSet<FieldReference>();
                    references.TryGetValue(references.Keys.ElementAt(j), out compareList);

                    for (int i = 0; i < compare.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (containsAllElements(compareList, compare)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

             return false;
        }

        private static bool containsAllElements(HashSet<FieldReference> compareList, HashSet<FieldReference> compare)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < compare.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!compareList.Contains(compare.ElementAt(i)))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static HashSet<FieldReference> calculateReferences(MethodDefinition method)
        {
            HashSet<FieldReference> references = new HashSet<FieldReference>();
            foreach (Instruction instruction in method.Body.Instructions)
            {
                if (instruction.OpCode == OpCodes.Ldfld)
                {
                    FieldReference field = instruction.Operand as FieldReference;
                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        references.Add(field);
                    }
                }
            }

            return references;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many pairs are there if key A/B/C all contains the same item "MyItem"?

Comment: Is this for .NET 2.0? (Lack of var in a verbose declaration makes me suspicious.) If it is, then it's important to mention because you might get a lot of LINQ answers that will not be useful to you.

Comment: I edited the question to answer comments.

Comment: but is that .NET 2.0 or can you use LINQ answers?

Comment: I completly edited the question so that it should be more clear now.

Comment: Fun note:  Went to go run your code in codepad.  Codepad doesn't support C#.  Cried a single tear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't tell us how can we tell two `FieldReference`s are duplicated, I will use the default.

LINQ version:

```
int duplicated = references.SelectMany( p => p.Value )
                           .GroupBy(x => x)
                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .Count();
```

Comment: This seems to really work nice! Can you shortly explain it pls?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: All methods are [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you don't mind keeping another dictionary, we can hit this thing with a big-durn-hammer.
Simply put, if we imagine a dictionary where ordered_set(field-references) is the key instead, and we keep a list of the values for each key....  Needless to say this isn't the most clever approach, but it is quick, easy, and uses data structures you are already familiar with.

EG:
 `hashset< hashset < FieldReference >, Ilist< methods >> Favorite_delicatessen`

Build ReferenceSet for method
Look up ReferenceSet in Favorite_Delicatessen
If there:
Add method to method list
Else:
Add Referenceset,method pair

And your methods list is thus the list of methods that share the same state-signature, if you'll let me coin a term.

Comment: It doesn't have to be very clever ;) It should just work for now :D If I understand you correctly you would just switch key and value?

Comment: Well.... Yes, basically.  Make sure that the field references are sorted, and I think you want them to be a set, unless I am mistaken, since what you care about is "Does The Function Touch This?" not "Is it touched repeatedly?"

Comment: Yes you're right, It is not good if repeated field access are there too. I used a set in my new solution (see edit), but I don't see yet where to use your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [ContainsValue](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys) to check for duplicates?  From what you described it appears you only have duplicates if the *values* are the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting a dictionary where the key is the duplicate item, and the value is a list of keys from the original dictionary that contain the duplicate:

```
var dupes = references
    .SelectMany(k => k.Value)
    .GroupBy(v => v)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => references
        .Where(f => f.Value.Contains(i.Key))
        .Select(o => o.Key));
```